# Typescript, @types/gulp gulp 4, browser-sync

Tags: typescript, types, gulp-4

Need help setting up this ts-project. Thanks in advance. There might be similar questions here but I could not find gulpfile.ts solution yet.

```js
//- package.json 

{
  "name": "cdd",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.html",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "gulp": "gulp"
  },
  "author": "vssadineni",
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/browser-sync": "^2.26.1",
    "@types/gulp": "^4.0.6",
    "@types/gulp-less": "0.0.31",
    "@types/node": "^12.12.7",
    "browser-sync": "^2.26.7",
    "gulp": "^4.0.2",
    "gulp-less": "^4.0.1",
    "gulp-typescript": "^5.0.1",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "ts-node": "^8.5.0",
    "typescript": "^3.7.2"
  }
}

//
//***********
//***********
//- My Gulpfile.ts

import gulp from 'gulp';
import less from 'gulp-less';
import g_ts from 'gulp-typescript';
import path from 'path';
import bSync from 'browser-sync';

let reload = bSync.reload;
bSync.create();

const ts = g_ts.createProject('tsconfig.json');
const paths = {
  style: {
    src: 'less/**/style.less',
    dest: 'dest/css'
  },
  scripts: {
    src: 'ts/**/*.ts',
    dest: 'dest/js'
  }
}

//- less css
export function styles() {
  return gulp.src(paths.style.src)
    .pipe(less({
      paths: [path.join(__dirname, 'less', 'includes')]
    })).on('error', console.error.bind(console))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.style.dest))
}

//- Browser Sync
export function browserSync(done: () => any) {
  bSync.init({
    server: {
      baseDir: './'
    },
    port: 4005
  });
  done();
}

//- TypeScripts Transpiling
export function types(done: () => any) {
  return ts.src()
    .pipe(ts())
    .pipe(gulp.src(paths.scripts.dest));
  done();
}


function Watch() {
  gulp.watch(paths.style.src, styles, reload)
  gulp.watch(paths.scripts.src, types, reload)
}

const sync = gulp.parallel(Watch, gulp.series(styles, types));
const build = gulp.series(gulp.parallel([styles, types], browserSync));

export {
  Watch as watch
}
const build = gulp.series(gulp.parallel(styles, types))
export default build;
```

//-- tscongif.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2018",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dest",
    "strict": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "typeRoots": [
      "./node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "sourceRoot": "src",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "declarationDir": "dest/js/d"
  }
}
```

And when I gulp it.

this is the error it is showing:

[17:17:03] Requiring external module ts-node/register

C:\vijay\projects\customDropdown\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:293
    return new TSError(diagnosticText, diagnosticCodes)
           ^
TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
gulpfile.ts:57:7 - error TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'build'.

57 const build = gulp.series(gulp.parallel([styles, types], browserSync));
         ~~~~~
gulpfile.ts:60:7 - error TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'build'.

60 const build = gulp.series(gulp.parallel(styles, g_ts))
         ~~~~~
gulpfile.ts:52:31 - error TS2559: Type '() => ReadWriteStream' has no properties in common with type 'WatchOptions'.

52   gulp.watch(paths.style.src, styles, reload)
                                 ~~~~~~
gulpfile.ts:53:33 - error TS2559: Type '(done: () => any) => ReadWriteStream' has no properties in common with type 'WatchOptions'.

53   gulp.watch(paths.scripts.src, types, reload)
                                   ~~~~~
gulpfile.ts:57:41 - error TS2345: Argument of type '((done: () => any) => ReadWriteStream)[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Task'.
  Type '((done: () => any) => ReadWriteStream)[]' is not assignable to type 'string'.

57 const build = gulp.series(gulp.parallel([styles, types], browserSync));
                                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

```
at createTSError (C:\vijay\projects\customDropdown\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:293:12)
at reportTSError (C:\vijay\projects\customDropdown\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:297:19)
at getOutput (C:\vijay\projects\customDropdown\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:399:34)
at Object.compile (C:\vijay\projects\customDropdown\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:457:32)
at Module.m._compile (C:\vijay\projects\customDropdown\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:530:43)
at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .ts] (C:\vijay\projects\customDropdown\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:533:12)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
```

most issues are resolved or it got only one now.
[image]

**error TS2345**: Argument of type '(() => ReadWriteStream)[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Task'. Type '(() => ReadWriteStream)[]' is not assignable to type 'string'.

Comment: As I am searching for a solution I found " https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node " link for adding " ts-node/register " and it is going way above my head. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The error is not related to typescript/gulp at all.
You have declared your function `build` twice.

Comment: My bad !... I corrected it yet || getting the issue: return new TSError(diagnosticText, diagnosticCodes) TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
gulpfile.ts:52:31 - error TS2559: Type '() => ReadWriteStream' has no properties in common with type 'WatchOptions'. || I am unable to past complete error here.

Comment: Now this is a typescript error. Your gulpfile is also a typescript file. Either convert it to js, or inspect the compilation error

Comment: Yes gulpfile is also .ts file and I would want it to be so. I think it should work.

Comment: Maybe it will, haven't used it like that. It means that first, you need to compile your gulpfile to js, and the error is coming because one of the `styles` or `types` functions are not compatible with the type to be provided to `gulp.series`. You can try casting them to `any` to check if this is the problem